# Really weird JS/HTML error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

To start, I have really limited knowledge in javascript so some of the terms that I may be using may be completely off, but I've tried to describe it as best as possible.

I've got a really strange problem going on... I've been trying to edit someone elses JS script because there's no point me making my own if they've already got most of the features I want. The problem is near the bottom of the JS script inserted into the html directly, specificaly the ones that actually connect the script to ID's in the HTML code, like "document.getElementById("playerAdmin").innerHTML = playerAdmin;". As you can see, it is rather messy there compared to the rest because I've had to keep messing around with it due to the reaosn that they only randomly seem to be working, so I have to keep messing around with the order that these things go in. For example, instead of:

```
        document.getElementById("playerID").innerHTML = playerID;
    document.getElementById("playerWanted").innerHTML = wanted;
    document.getElementById("playerBankMoney").innerHTML = bank;
```

I might have to swap the order of it to:

```
document.getElementById("playerWanted").innerHTML = wanted;
    document.getElementById("playerBankMoney").innerHTML = bank;
document.getElementById("playerID").innerHTML = playerID;
```

Because one of the ID's don't seem to be working - there is nothing in the code that suggests to me why this is happening, and it does really seem quite random to me - in general, it seems that whatever code is under the 'broken piece' (which again, is selected randomly) stops functioning.

```js
function parseURLParams(url) {
  var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
    queryEnd = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
    query = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1),
    pairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&"),
    parms = {},
    i, n, v, nv;

  if (query === url || query === "") return;

  for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    nv = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
    n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
    v = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);

    if (!parms.hasOwnProperty(n)) parms[n] = [];
    parms[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
  }
  return parms;
}

var urlParams = parseURLParams(document.location.href);
console.log(urlParams);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  height: 59px
}

div.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

div.header a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: deepskyblue;
}

div.header a.active {
  color: deepskyblue;
}

body {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAGklEQVQYV2NkwAIYCQkaMzAwnAUpIqgSbhIAMXABBoGmkP0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  background-color: rgba(44, 105, 140, 0.1);
  background-position: center center;
}

h1.title {
  color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 140px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

h1.title span {
  color: deepskyblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.search {
  width: 80%;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

div.search a {
  color: deepskyblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

div.search a:hover {
  color: white;
}

i {
  border: solid deepskyblue;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  right: 15px;
}

div.result {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: rgba(35, 56, 89, 0.9);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

div.result:hover {
  background-color: rgba(35, 56, 89, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

div.result h2 {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div.result h3 {
  color: lightgray;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.playerdata {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  padding: 20px;
}

div.playerdata img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}

div.playerdata h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div.playerdata div.head {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid deepskyblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em
}

div.playerdata div.head button {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: solid deepskyblue 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div.playerdata div.head h2 {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div.playerdata div.head button:hover {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div.playerdata div.info {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-bottom: 5px solid deepskyblue;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

span.result {
  color: lightgray !important;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.right {
  border-left: 5px solid deepskyblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  min-height: 350px;
}

div.playerdata div.info p {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div.net .hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.net:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 0.5s;
  animation: fadeEffect 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

div.vehicle .hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.vehicle:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

.hidden span {
  color: white;
}

div.license div.hidden {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

div.license:hover div.hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

span.true {
  background-color: lawngreen;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

span.false {
  background-color: orangered;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.playerdata div.info p:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: default;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.police p {
  background-color: rgb(70, 133, 201);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.police:hover p {
  background-color: rgba(70, 133, 201, 0.9);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.police p.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.police:hover p.hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.nhs p {
  background-color: rgb(94, 206, 74);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.nhs:hover p {
  background-color: rgba(94, 206, 74, 0.9);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.nhs p.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.nhs:hover p.hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.unmc p {
  background-color: rgb(201, 70, 70);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.unmc:hover p {
  background-color: rgba(201, 70, 70, 0.9);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.unmc p.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.unmc:hover p.hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.gang p {
  background-color: rgb(133, 70, 201);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.gang:hover p {
  background-color: rgba(133, 70, 201, 0.9);
}

div.playerdata div.info div.gang p.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.playerdata div.info div.gang:hover p.hidden {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(35, 56, 89);
  color: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stats page</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/urlParse.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var request = "https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/" + "76561198062083666";

    var leaderBoardsRequest = "https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/statistics/leaderboards";
    var leaderboardsData = "";

    var data = "";

    function numberWithCommas(x) {
      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    function error(data) {
      console.log(url);
      var playerIdExpression = new RegExp("765611[0-9]{11}$");
      var guidExpression = new RegExp("[a-f0-9]{32}$");
      var request = "https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/" + "76561198062083666";
      try {
        if (typeof urlParams['q'][0] !== 'undefined') {
          if (playerIdExpression.test(urlParams['q'][0]) == false && guidExpression.test(urlParams['q'][0]) == false) {
            window.location.replace("https://stats.roleplay.co.uk/400.html");
          } else {
            window.location.replace("https://stats.roleplay.co.uk/error.html?errorCode=500&errorQ=" + window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf("?q=")) + "&q=" + urlParams['q'][0] + "?apiQ=" + request);
          }
        } else {
          window.location.replace("https://stats.roleplay.co.uk/400.html");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        window.location.replace("https://stats.roleplay.co.uk/404.html");
      }
    }

    function success(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var isPolice = false;
      var isUNMC = false;
      var isNHS = false;
      var isGroup = false;

      var playerName = data['name'];
      var playerID = data['steamid'];
      var steamName = data.steam['name'];
      var playerWorth = "£" + numberWithCommas(data['bank'] + data['cash']);
      var bank = "£" + numberWithCommas(data['bank']);
      var cash = "£" + numberWithCommas(data['cash']);
      var playerGroups = [];
      var wanted = data['wanted'];
      var vehicleCount = data['vehicles']['length'];
      var playerAdmin = "Not Staff";
      var prank = "Not Police";
      var nhsrank = "Not NHS";
      var urank = "Not UNMC";
      var undercover = data['undercoverrank'];
      var licencesall = data.civ_licenses;
      var licencesfinal = [];

      document.title = playerName + " - Roleplay UK - Stats";

      for (l = 0; l < data.civ_licenses['length']; l++) {
        if (data.civ_licenses[l].owned == true) {
          licencesfinal.push(data.civ_licenses[l]);
        }
      }

      switch (wanted) {
        case true:
          wanted = "Player Wanted!";
          break;
        case false:
          wanted = "Player Not Wanted!";
          break;
      }

      var guid = data['guid'];

      if (data['policerank'] > 0) {
        playerGroups.push("Altis Police");

        var units = [];

        switch (data['arrank']) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            units.push("Armed Response");
            break;
        }
        switch (data['ncarank']) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            units.push("National Crime Agency");
            break;
        }
        switch (data['npasrank']) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            units.push("NPAS Tier 1");
            break;
          case 2:
            units.push("NPAS Tier 2");
            break;
          case 3:
            units.push("NPAS Tier 3");
            break;
        }

        switch (data['mporank']) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            units.push("MPO Tier 1");
            break;
          case 2:
            units.push("MPO Tier 2");
            break;
        }

        switch (undercover) {
          case "1":
            units.push("Undercover Permit");
            break;
        }

        if (units.length == 0) {
          units = "None";
        }

        for (f = 0; f < units.length; f++) {
          if (units.length == 5) {
            units = "All";
          } else if (f != units.length && f != 0) {
            units[f] = " " + units[f];
          }
          console.log(units);
        }

        switch (data['policerank']) {
          case 1:
            var prank = "Police Community Support Officer";
            break;
          case 2:
            var prank = "Probationary Police Constable";
            break;
          case 3:
            var prank = "Police Constable";
            break;
          case 4:
            var prank = "Sergeant";
            break;
          case 5:
            var prank = "Inspector";
            break;
          case 6:
            var prank = "Chief Inspector";
            break;
          case 7:
            var prank = "Superintendent";
            break;
          case 8:
            var prank = "Chief Superintendent";
            break;
          case 9:
            var prank = "Assistant Chief Constable";
            break;
          case 10:
            var prank = "Deputy Chief Constable";
            break;
          case 11:
            var prank = "Chief Constable";
            break;
        }
        isPolice = true;
      }

      if (data['unmcrank'] > 0) {
        playerGroups.push("UNMC");
        switch (data['unmcrank']) {
          case 1:
            var urank = "Recruit";
            break;
          case 2:
            var urank = "Private";
            break;
          case 3:
            var urank = "Private First Class";
            break;
          case 4:
            var urank = "Lance Corporal";
            break;
          case 5:
            var urank = "Corporal";
            break;
          case 6:
            var urank = "Sergeant";
            break;
          case 7:
            var urank = "Staff Sergeant";
            break;
          case 8:
            var urank = "Sergeant Major";
            break;
          case 9:
            var urank = "Lieutenant";
            break;
          case 10:
            var urank = "Captain";
            break;
          case 11:
            var urank = "Major";
            break;
          case 12:
            var urank = "Colonel";
            break;
          case 13:
            var urank = "General";
            break;
        }
        isUNMC = true;
      }

      if (data['nhsrank'] > 0) {
        playerGroups.push("NHS");

        var nhsunits = [];

        switch (data['nhsarrank']) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            nhsunits.push("Air Rescue Tier 1");
            break;
          case 2:
            nhsunits.push("Air Rescue Tier 2");
            break;
          case 3:
            nhsunits.push("Air Rescue Tier 3");
            break;
        }
        switch (data['nhsrirrank']) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            nhsunits.push("Road Incident Responder");
            break;
        }

        if (nhsunits.length == 0) {
          units = "None";
        }

        for (g = 0; g < nhsunits.length; g++) {
          if (g != nhsunits.length && g != 0) {
            nhsunits[g] = " " + nhsunits[g];
          }
        }

        switch (data['nhsrank']) {
          case 1:
            var nhsrank = "Student";
            break;
          case 2:
            var nhsrank = "First Aider";
            break;
          case 3:
            var nhsrank = "Paramedic";
            break;
          case 4:
            var nhsrank = "Surgeon";
            break;
          case 5:
            var nhsrank = "Doctor";
            break;
          case 6:
            var nhsrank = "Consultant";
            break;
          case 7:
            var nhsrank = "NHS Administration";
            break;
          case 8:
            var nhsrank = "Chief Medical Officer";
            break;
        }
        isNHS = true;
      }

      if (data['grouprank'] > 0) {
        playerGroups.push(data['groupname']);
        isGroup = true;
      }

      if (data['adminlevel'] > 0 && data['adminlevel'] <= 4) {
        playerAdmin = "Staff Team - Level " + data['adminlevel'];
      } else if (data['adminlevel'] == 5) {
        playerAdmin = "Staff Team - Lead " + data['adminlevel'];
      } else if (data['adminlevel'] == 6) {
        playerAdmin = "Management";
      } else if (data['adminlevel'] == 7) {
        playerAdmin = "Developer";
      }
      //Putting the commas in the right places and formatting it nicely

      if (playerGroups.length == 0) {
        playerGroups = "None";
      }

      for (i = 0; i <= playerGroups.length; i++) {
        if (i != playerGroups.length && i != 0) {
          playerGroups[i] = " " + playerGroups[i]
        }
      }

      if (data['groupname'] == null) {
        data['groupname'] = "<b>Not in a group</b>";
      }
      document.getElementById("playerAdmin").innerHTML = playerAdmin;
      document.getElementById("playerID").innerHTML = playerID;
      document.getElementById("playerWanted").innerHTML = wanted;
      document.getElementById("playerBankMoney").innerHTML = bank;
      document.getElementById("playerCashMoney").innerHTML = cash;

      document.getElementById("playerTotalMoney").innerHTML = playerWorth;
      document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = playerName;
      document.getElementById("playerTotalMoney").innerHTML = playerWorth;

      document.getElementById("playerVehicleCount").innerHTML = vehicleCount;
      if (prank != "Not Police") {
        document.getElementById("playerPoliceRank").innerHTML = prank + "<br/>";
        document.getElementById("playerSpecUnits").innerHTML = "Specialist Units: <b>" + units + "</b>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("playerPoliceRank").innerHTML = prank + "";
        document.getElementById("playerSpecUnits").style.display = "none";
      }
      if (nhsrank != "Not NHS") {
        document.getElementById("playerNHSRank").innerHTML = nhsrank + "<br/>";
        document.getElementById("playerNHSSpecUnits").innerHTML = "Branches: <b>" + nhsunits + "</b>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("playerNHSRank").innerHTML = nhsrank + "";
        document.getElementById("playerNHSSpecUnits").style.display = "none";
      }
      document.getElementById("groupLabel").innerHTML = data['groupname'];
      if (data['groupname'] != "<b>Not in a group</b>") {
        document.getElementById("groupLabel").innerHTML = data['groupname'];
        document.getElementById("playerGroupRank").innerHTML = data['grouprank'];
      }
      document.getElementById("playerGUID").innerHTML = guid;

      document.getElementById("playerUNMCRank").innerHTML = urank;
      document.getElementById("groupLabel").innerHTML = data['groupname'];

      if (playerName.length > 13) {
        playerNameDisplay = playerName.substring(0, 10) + "...";
      } else {
        playerNameDisplay = playerName;
      }

      if (data['forumid'] != null) {
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML += " <a href='" + data['forumurl'] + "' class='button'>Forum Profile</a>";
      }

      if (data.steam['profileurl'] != null) {
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML += " <a href='" + data.steam['profileurl'] + "' class='button'>Steam Profile</a>";
      }

      document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML += " <span><a href='https://www.roleplay.co.uk/forms/4-report-a-player/?form_field_26=" + escape(playerName) + "' class='button'>Report</a></span>";
      document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML += " <span><a href='https://www.roleplay.co.uk/forum/123-recommend-a-player/?do=add&topic_title=" + escape(playerName) + "&topic_tags=" + playerID + "' class='button'>Recommend</a></span>";

      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: leaderBoardsRequest,
        data: leaderboardsData
      });
    }

    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: request,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      error: error
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=playerdata>
    <div class=head>
      <h1 id="playerName">...</h1>
      <h2 id="playerID">...</h2>
      <button>Steam Profile</button>
      <button>Forum Profile</button>
      <button>Report</button>
      <button>Recommend</button>
    </div>
    <div class=info>
      <div class=general>
        <h2>General Information</h2>
        <div class=net>
          <p id=playerTotalMoney>...</p>
          <p class=hidden><span>Bank: </span><span class=result id=playerBankMoney>...</span><br><span>Cash On Hand: </span><span class=result id=playerCashMoney>...</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class=vehicle>
          <p id=playerVehicleCount>...</p>
          <p class=hidden>'VEHICLE LIST'</p>
        </div>
        <div class=license>
          <p>'LICENSES'</p>
          <div class=hidden><span class=true>Cement</span><span class=true>Copper</span><span class=false>Iron</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class=wanted>
          <p id=playerWanted>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class=admin>
          <p id=playerAdmin>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h2>Organisations</h2>
        <div class=police>
          <p id=playerPoliceRank>...</p>
          <p class=hidden><span>Last Logon: </span><span class=result id=policelog>...</span><br><span id=npas class=false>...</span><span id=mpo class=false>...</span><span id=ar class=false>...</span><span id=nca class=false>...</span><span id=rtu class=false>...</span>
            <span
              id=undercover class=false>...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class=nhs>
          <p id=playerNHSRank>...</p>
          <p class=hidden><span>Last Logon: </span><span class=result id=nhslog>...</span><br><span class=true>Undercover</span><span class=false>NCA</span><span class=true>AR</span><span class=true>MPO</span><span class=false>NPAS</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class=unmc>
          <p>'UNMC RANK'</p>
          <p class=hidden><span>Last Logon: </span><span class=result id=unmclog>...</span><br><span class=true>Undercover</span><span class=false>NCA</span><span class=true>AR</span><span class=true>MPO</span><span class=false>NPAS</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class=gang>
          <p id=groupLabel>...</p>
          <p class=hidden><span>Last Logon:</span> 10/09/08 12:11:10<br><span class=true>Undercover</span><span class=false>NCA</span><span class=true>AR</span><span class=true>MPO</span><span class=false>NPAS</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What "broken piece"?  What specifically is failing?  Is there an error in your browser's debugging console?  When you use your browser's debugger, where/how specifically is the code failing?

Comment: An example of this failure is with the playerNHSRank id - I've setup the code exactly the same as the police code, along with the script, yet the script fails to change the '...' to the required value.
This is one of the error I receive, which I think relates to this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Object.success (player.html:340)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Well, you certainly can't set an `innerHTML` property on a `null` object.  Focus specifically on the line which is throwing that error.  Does the element you're looking for exist at the time that line executes?  There's *a lot* of code here, perhaps somewhere before that line you modify the HTML to be different from what's being shown?  Also, technically your HTML isn't valid.  Attributes should be enclosed in double-quotes.  Some of yours are, most aren't.  All should be.  Browsers try to correct broken HTML automatically, and the result isn't always what you expect it would be.

Comment: It's telling me that the following code is the problem as it would equal null:

document.getElementById("playerSpecUnits").innerHTML = ("Specialist Units: <b>" + "units" + "</b>");

But I really don't see how that equals null (that is edited code, by the way, to try and get it to work - usually it's like below):

document.getElementById("playerSpecUnits").innerHTML = "Specialist Units: <b>" + units + "</b>";

Comment: Well, I don't see any element in your HTML with `id="playerSpecUnits"`.

Comment: Yup that's fixed it... thanks so much!
I don't really understand how that works though - I thought that the script meant that if there was an element with id 'playerSpecUnits' it would apply that part of the script to them. I don't 100% understand why it doesn't just ignore that part of the script if there is no element with the relevant ID?

Comment: You're probably thinking of jQuery selectors, which would silently fail.  (Or, more accurately, would successfully apply the change to a list of 0 elements.)  When calling `getElementById()` (and other similar native JavaScript functions), one must verify that the element is found before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this runs before the DOM is loaded:

```
 $.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: request,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  error: error
 });
```

That may be the reason the errors your'e getting are random.

Maybe you should try something like:

```
function ajaxLoad(){
     $.ajax({
         dataType: 'json',
         url: request,
         data: data,
         success: success,
         error: error
         });
     }
window.onload = ajaxLoad;
```

It's also best practice to put/load whatever javascript (code or file) you have by the end of the document.